# why wont my else if statements work

Tags: javascript, html

Hello everyone i am not really sure why my else if statements aren't working as i intend to have them run on the click of a button and each else if question run until one of them is true and returns the 'correct' or 'wrong' boxes. Are my else if statements even being called on correctly? And if so am i referring to the 'correctAnswer' correctly? Thanks in advance!:)(oh and by the way the display style of the 'wrong' and 'correct' divs are set to 'none' in an external css stylesheet)

The Javascript:

```
var gameOn = false;
var score;
var interval;
Array.prototype.shuffle = function(){
            var i = this.length, j, temp;
            while(--i > 0){
                j = Math.floor(Math.random() * (i+1));
                temp = this[j];
                this[j] = this[i];
                this[i] = temp;  
              }//while loop bracket
            return this;
        }

function stopGame() {
  gameOn = false;
  if (interval) {
    clearInterval(interval);
    interval = null;
  }//if interval bracket
  document.getElementById("startreset").innerHTML = "Start Game";
  document.getElementById("time-remaining").style.display = "";
}//function stopGame bracket


//if we click on the start/reset
document.getElementById("startreset").onclick = function () {

  //if we are not playing
  if (gameOn) {
    stopGame();
  }/*if gameOn bracket*/ else {

      //change mode to playing
    gameOn = true;

    //set score to 0
    score = 0;

    document.getElementById("scorevalue").innerHTML = score;

    //show countdown box
    document.getElementById("time-remaining").style.display = "block";
    document.getElementById("startreset").innerHTML = "Reset Game";

    var counter = 60;

    //reduce time by 1sec in loops
    interval = setInterval(timeIt, 1000);
    function timeIt(){
      document.getElementById("timer-down").innerHTML = counter;
      counter--;

        //timeleft?
        //no->gameover
        if ( counter === 0) {
        stopGame();
        document.getElementById("game-over").style.display = "block";
        document.getElementById("game-over").innerHTML = "Game Over" + "<br />" + "<br />" + "Your Score is " + score + "!";

        }//if counter bracket
    }//timeIt function bracket

      //generate new Q&A
      generateQA();
      function generateQA(){
        //this is the first number in the equation  
        var Na = 1+ Math.round(Math.random() * 9);
        //this is the second number in the equation   
        var Nb  = 1+ Math.round(Math.random() * 9);
        //the correct answer is when you multiply both together  
        correctAnswer = Na * Nb;
        //these are the randomly generated wrong answers  
        var w1 = 1+ Math.round(Math.random() * 16);
        var w3 = 1+ Math.round(Math.random() * 22);
        var w4 = 1+ Math.round(Math.random() * 92);  
        document.getElementById("question").innerHTML = Na + "x" + Nb;
        console.log(correctAnswer);

        var myArray = [w1, correctAnswer, w3, w4];
        var result = myArray.shuffle();

        document.getElementById("box1").innerHTML = result[0];
        document.getElementById("box2").innerHTML = result[1];
        document.getElementById("box3").innerHTML = result[2];
        document.getElementById("box4").innerHTML = result[3];

        }//generateQA function bracket

        function evaluateAnswer(){
            var a = document.getElementById("correct");
            var b = document.getElementById("wrong");
            if ('box1' === correctAnswer){
                a.style.diplay = 'block';
                generateQA();
            }else if('box1' !== correctAnswer){
                b.style.diplay = 'block';
            }else if('box2' === correctAnswer){
                a.style.diplay = 'block';
                generateQA();
            }else if('box2' !== correctAnswer){
                b.style.diplay = 'block';
            }else if('box3' === correctAnswer){
                a.style.diplay = 'block';
                generateQA();
            }else if('box3' !== correctAnswer){
                b.style.diplay = 'block';
            }else if('box4' === correctAnswer){
                a.style.diplay = 'block';
                generateQA();
            }else if('box4' !== correctAnswer){
                b.style.diplay = 'block';
            }
          }//evaluateAnswer function bracket

    }//else statement bracket
}//startreset button function bracket
```

The HTML:

```
<div id="correct">
Correct!
            </div>
            <div id="wrong">
                Try Again
            </div>
            <div id="question">
                <span id="firstInt"></span><span id="secondInt"></span>
            </div>
            <div id="instruction">
                Click on the Correct Answer
            </div>
            <div id="choices">
                <div id="box1" onclick = "evaluateAnswer()" class="boxes"></div>
                <div id="box2" onclick = "evaluateAnswer()" class="boxes"></div>
                <div id="box3" onclick = "evaluateAnswer()" class="boxes"></div>
                <div id="box4" onclick = "evaluateAnswer()" class="boxes"></div>
            </div>
            <div id="startreset">
                Start Game
            </div>
```

Comment: There is no function named `correctAnswer`. This is a variable, mabye you mean to drop the `()` part: `if ('box1' === correctAnswer)`.

Comment: You at one point change the style of a `div` with id: `game-over`, but you do not have that div in your html.

Comment: @SpencerWieczorek Thanks for that and ya i just got rid of the parenthesis and i am lead to a question...is the correctAnswer variable being accessed by my evaluateAnswer funtion? Or should i try and make it a global variable?

Comment: @chris sorry chris i didnt but that part of the html in the post because that part works already and im trying to focus on how i could get the evalutation of the correct answer to work properly:)

Comment: `correctAnswer` is a number, but you compare it to strings like `'box1'`. The result of course is never true. Also, are you aware that your random routines do not generate numbers with equal probability. For instance, `Math.round(Math.random() * 9)` generates 8 twice as often as it generates 9.

Comment: @MrLister im not worried so much about the equal probability of the randomness as its meant to be a kids math game and its ok in my opinion if there are slightly higher chance of repeating numbers as it would help them with that number group. But can you go a little more into depth on the correct answer and the box1, why wouldnt it ever be true exactly(im not disagreeing with you at all im just a newbie and im curious)

Answer (score 1):

Beyond the comments to your question your logic is broken.

```js
if ('box1' === correctAnswer()){
  a.style.diplay = 'block';
  generateQA();
}else if('box1' !== correctAnswer()){
  b.style.diplay = 'block';
}
```

Your first `if` and second `if` are mutually exclusive which means that one of those two will always be true. All of the other `else` operations will not execute.

**UPDATE** - Includes changes based on your latest comment.

Since you are just trying to indicate if the answer is right or not then try something like this:

You would need to move the location of `result` to global:

```
var result = [];
```

With result being a global variable then you could change the rest of your code to be something like this:

```js
function evaluateAnswer(box){
  var a = document.getElementById("correct");
  var b = document.getElementById("wrong");

  if (result[box] === correctAnswer) {
    a.style.diplay = 'block';
    b.style.diplay = 'none';
    generateQA();
  } else {
    a.style.diplay = 'none';
    b.style.diplay = 'block';
  }
}//evaluateAnswer function bracket
```

```html
<div id="correct">Correct!</div>
<div id="wrong">Try Again</div>
<div id="question">
  <span id="firstInt"></span>
  <span id="secondInt"></span>
</div>
<div id="instruction">
  Click on the Correct Answer
</div>
<div id="choices">
  <div id="box1" onclick="evaluateAnswer(0)" class="boxes"></div>
  <div id="box2" onclick="evaluateAnswer(1)" class="boxes"></div>
  <div id="box3" onclick="evaluateAnswer(2)" class="boxes"></div>
  <div id="box4" onclick="evaluateAnswer(3)" class="boxes"></div>
</div>
<div id="startreset">
  Start Game
</div>
```

This line:

```
  if (result[box] === correctAnswer) {
```

would test to see if the correct box was clicked on.

This is the changed HTML:

```
  <div id="box1" onclick="evaluateAnswer(0)" class="boxes"></div>
  <div id="box2" onclick="evaluateAnswer(1)" class="boxes"></div>
  <div id="box3" onclick="evaluateAnswer(2)" class="boxes"></div>
  <div id="box4" onclick="evaluateAnswer(3)" class="boxes"></div>
```

When the user clicks on the various boxes the `onClick` handler calls the `evaluateAnswer` function and passes in the index of the box was clicked on. The `0` to `3` indicate the box number and also the index of answer stored in the `result` array. `0` is `results[0]`, `1` is `results[1]`, etc.

Since you would be storing the answers in the `results` array, then you only need to coordinate between what the user clicks on and what the answer is for that box. If they click on box 1 then `evaluateAnswer(0)` is called. That function uses the `0` to look up the answer in `results[0]`. If that is the correct answer then you shows the *correct* message. Otherwise it shows the *wrong* message.

Comment: I think i kinda get the idea of what you mean by that. So because if it is the correct answer then it will change the 'a' display to block and if its not then the 'b' display will turn to block potentially terminating the code there, but how could i allow the other else if questions to run in a case like this? I am not sure how else to address that

Comment: what is a efficient way to track the position of my correctAnswer based on the Math.random that generates my random numbers...I dont know how to track the correct answer

Comment: this didnt work for me:( and also im not really sure what the (0)(1)(2)(3) after evaluateAnswer would do. and what does the parseInt do to?

Comment: Changes made to my answer.

Comment: The approach seems accurate and i think it might work but i have one more question. You said to make var result a global location but isnt 'var result = myArray.shuffle();' ? So would i leave that inside the generateQA function and then also add at the top var result = [];? or is it one or the other...

Answer (score 0):

I don't if this helps you but I renamed some of your functions because they didn't make sense. Also if your going to name a lot of variables up top your better off doing like below. Also your missing the ending div for your correct div. Better to use an ternary operator if your doing a simple if/else statement.

```
   var gameOn = false,
        score,
        interval,
        startBtn = document.getElementById('startReset'),
        timer = document.getElementById("time-remaining"); 

    Array.prototype.shuffle = function(){
                var i = this.length, j, temp;
                while(--i > 0){
                    j = Math.floor(Math.random() * (i+1));
                    temp = this[j];
                    this[j] = this[i];
                    this[i] = temp;  
                  }//while loop bracket
                return this;
            }

    function stopGame() {
      gameOn = false;
      startBtn.innerHTML = "Start Game";
      //   timer.style.display = "none";
      // marked out will throw error not on html 
    }

    function startGame() {
      gameOn = true; 
      startBtn.innerHTML = 'Stop Game'; 

    }
    function checkGameStatus() {
        console.log(gameOn)
         gameOn ? stopGame() : startGame(); 
      }


    startBtn.addEventListener('click', checkGameStatus);
```